# Cassandra Subquery Alternate

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am looking for this code for cassandra;

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE col_1 IN (SELECT col_1 FROM table_2 WHERE col_2=2)
```

Is there any correspond code for cassandra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two of Cassandra's core concepts is that the tables are designed to serve one query and it does not support these kinds of selects. Of course, you could do that at your application level.

So, the answer in no, it won't support such query.

Comment: It does not to be like this. If you could enhance your schema, you can have a table that would contain the data so you don't need to do this kinds of selects